# Get the frequency of the elements in a column

Tags: python, r, loops, count

I have a directory with several files tab-delimited (txt format). Each file is a table with a lot of rows, but I am interested in the 10th column. I want to extract all uniq values of this column and count the occurrence for all files. For this purpose, I have used the code below in bash, which works, but when the files are extremely heavy, it does not respond.

```
awk -F'\t' 'FNR==1{next}
{
  ++n[$10];
  if ($10 in a) {
    a[$10]=a[$10]","ARGV[ARGIND]
  }else{
    a[$10]=ARGV[ARGIND]
  }
}
END{
printf("%-24s %6s    %s\n","Variant","Nº of repeats","Location");
for (v in n) printf("%-24s %6d    %s\n",v,n[v],a[v])}' * > var_freq.txt
```

The output should see something like this:

```
Variant     Nº of repeats     Location
variant1    3     file1,file2,file3
variant2    5     file1,file3,file4,file5,file7
variant3    2     file1,file4
```

The header of a possible file looks like this:

```
Chr     Start     END    COL4     COL5     COL6     COL7     COL8     COL9     Variant
1     1234     1345    ABC     123     234     345     456     567     c.1236A>G
```

Anyone could tell me how to do that in other languages that can handle BigData? (python, R...)
Thanks

Comment: You can do it in Python for sure.
I don't have time here to transpose your awk script to Python.
But the global idea, once you'll have read the content of the file in memory is to iterate over its rows.
Then `row.split()` will give a list of 10 "fields" (equivalent to your `-F'\t'`).
And you'll find variant at position 9 (index begin at 0).
`variant = row.split()[9]`.

Comment: I don't know `awk` very well but I suspect it's reading in the entire file into memory which is why it's not responding. You should be reading the file in digestible chunks, storing the values you need, and then read in a new chunk. E.g. https://medium.com/developer-space/working-with-large-files-741c99dac70d

Comment: Have you tried the same procedure using`gnu awk` (`gawk`) it handles much higher numbers of fields than `awk` and, depending if that was the problem with awk, will likely fix it.

Comment: @aydow `awk` processes files line-by-line, not as an entire file. That said, it does have field number limits, hence my suggestion above of using `gawk` which can process millions of fields.

Comment: @DavePritlove thanks for your suggestion! I have tried, but it happens the same thing with awk

Comment: To be clear, I was suggesting `gawk` *instead of* `awk`. Another thought, looking at your procedure, I think (although haven't tested) that `a[$10]=a[$10]","ARGV[ARGIND]` might be a problem. Later lines may(/will In longer files) have the same value for `$10` and so will try to increment an array value that has a file name appended to it. I would suggest you add the filenames to separate array keys maybe ` `a[$10"F"]` or similar so that you can increment numerical values in `a[$10]`. It should be easy to reference the right file index for each value count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option in R:

```r
library(data.table)

file_list <- list.files(pattern = "\\.txt")

myData <- lapply(file_list, \(x){
  dat <- fread(x, select = 10) |>
    table() |>
    data.table()
  dat[,file := sub("\\.txt", "", x)]
}) |>
  rbindlist()

final <- myData[, .(`Nº of repeats` = sum(N), Location = paste(file, collapse = ",")),
            by = list(Variant = V1)]

print(final)
```

Comment: It seems that it works, but I found out that if I have 200 files, the max number of variants should be 200 (if they are unique, should be), is there a way to see what files contain the same variant more than once?

Comment: what would the expected output be?

Comment: The number of repeats should be the same as the number of files in "Location" because the variant should be unique (let me revise the files :D). In any case, is there a way to add another column that should be the same for all? for example, if the value of Variant is "c.1236A>G", the value of column 9 is "nonsynonymous", and so on. if it is hard I will open a new question

Comment: I would probably open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

**In R**

Load these packages:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
```

Then, given that you have a vector `files` with your file names, you can find the counts of the variants with:

```r
files %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(
    \(file) {
      read.delim(file) %>%
        select(10) %>%
        table() %>%
        enframe(name = "Variant", value = "N") %>%
        mutate(Location = file)
    }
  ) %>%
  group_by(Variant) %>%
  summarize(`N° of repeats` = sum(N),
            Location = paste0(Location, collapse = ","),
            .groups = "drop")
```

You can install the dependencies from the R console with:

```r
install.packages(c("dplyr", "purrr", "tibble"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R

```
mydir <- "/location/of/my/dir"
files <- list.files(filedir, pattern = "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)

variants <- lapply(seq_along(files), \(i) data.frame(
  "Location" = basename(files[i]),
  "Variant" = unique(read.delim(files[i])[,10])
))

output <- aggregate(Location~Variant, do.call(rbind, variants), paste, sep=",")
output$Nrepeats <- nchar(gsub("[^,]", "", output$Location)) + 1

> output
   Variant                        Location Nrepeats
1 variant1            file1.csv, file3.csv        2
2 variant2            file1.csv, file2.csv        2
3 variant3                       file1.csv        1
4 variant4 file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv        3
5 variant5                       file2.csv        1
6 variant6            file2.csv, file3.csv        2
7 variant9                       file3.csv        1
```

1. Create a vector of filenames
2. For each filename, create a data frame like this:

```
> variants[[1]]
   Location  Variant
1 file1.csv variant1
2 file1.csv variant2
3 file1.csv variant3
4 file1.csv variant4
```

3. Stick all the data frames together and aggregate by Variant (you're left with one row per variant)
4. Count the number of filenames to populate Nrepeats (this is a bit inefficient and you could use two separate aggregations or tapplys instead)